# Interested in using Selenium to test XML / VXML pages

Tags: xml, selenium, vxml

Is there a way to use selenium to test VXML pages? I seem to only be able to access HTML content. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this patch to Selenium RC, seems to be working for some people:

http://www.mernin.com/blog/2007/02/adding-xml-support-to-selenium-remote-control/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Selenium web site, it looks like it is specifically parsing and processing the HTML pages.  Therefore, it's parser wouldn't work with VXML.

Answer (score 0):

There's a commercial tool named [NuBot](http://www.nuecho.com/content/view/28/147) that can test VoiceXML pages as well as speech/DTMF grammars.  It can be a bit expensive (a few thousand dollars for a large-scale installation) to get started, but it rapidly pays for itself if you are serious about automated testing.